# Proving $n!n^s=o(n^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms, asymptotics

I want to prove that for any $s\geq0$, and $n\to\infty$, $n!n^s=o(n^n)$ or $$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{n!n^s}{n^n}=0.$$ As a hint, the inequality $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\log k\leq n\log\frac{n+1}2$$ is given.

I thought that instead of proving $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}n!n^{s-n}=0$, one could also show $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\log\left(n!n^{s-n}\right)=-\infty$. This would be equivalent to $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\log\left(n!\right)+\log\left(n^{s-n}\right)=-\infty$. Using the given inequality, it would be sufficient to prove $$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}n\log\frac{n+1}2+\log\left(n^{s-n}\right)=-\infty\Leftrightarrow\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}n\log\frac{n+1}{2n}+s\log n=-\infty\\\Leftrightarrow\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}n\log\frac12+s\log n=-\infty.$$
What should I do now?

Comment: beware simplifying $\ln(\frac{n+1}{2n})$ directly to $\ln(\frac 12)$ would be better to use $o$ notation to get $n\ln(\frac 12)+n\ln(1+\frac 1n)+s\ln n=-n\ln 2+n(\frac 1n+o(\frac 1n))+s\ln n$ and use then $\ln n=o(n)$ to justify that all this is equivalent to $-n\ln(2)\to-\infty$ rather than carrying limits symbols along the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series
$$\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty\frac{n!n^s}{n^n}$$
is convergent by the ratio test (easy exercise). Therefore
$$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{n!n^s}{n^n}=0.$$

Comment: Hehe, the old trickery:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=0\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Yes. I think that this trick is underused :)

Answer (score 2):

Using the hint given,

\begin{align}
\log \left( \frac{n! n^s}{n^n} \right)
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \log(k) + \log\left(\frac{n^s}{n^n}\right)\\
&\leq n\log\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) + \log\left(\frac{n^s}{n^n}\right)\\
&= \log\left( \frac{(n+1)^n}{2^n} \cdot \frac{n^s}{n^n}\right)\\
&= \log\left( \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \cdot \frac{n^s}{2^n}\right)
\end{align}
By exponentiation

\begin{align}
0 \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n! n^s}{n^n}
\leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \cdot \frac{n^s}{2^n}
= e \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^s}{2^n} = 0
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Write
\begin{align}
n\log\left(\frac{n+1}{2n}\right) + s \log n = n \left(\log\left(\frac{n+1}{2n}\right) + s\cdot\frac{\log n}{n}\right)
\end{align}
Now since
$$
\log\left(\frac{n+1}{2n}\right) + s\cdot\frac{\log n}{n} \to \log\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) < 0
$$
it follows that
$$
n \left(\log\left(\frac{n+1}{2n}\right) + s\cdot\frac{\log n}{n}\right) \to -\infty
$$

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the hint, let $m=\lceil s\rceil$.  Then, for $n\gt m+1$, we have

$${n!n^s\over n^n}\le{n!n^m\over n^n}=\left(n\over n\right)\left(n-1\over n\right)\cdots\left(m+2\over n\right)\left(m+1\over n\right)\left(mn\over n\right)\left((m-1)n\over n\right)\cdots\left(2n\over n\right)\left(1n\over n\right)\\
\le1\cdot1\cdots1\cdot\left(m+1\over n\right)m(m-1)\cdots2\cdot1={(m+1)!\over n}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to prove that $\frac{n!}{n^n}$ behaves more or less like $e^{-n}$. $\log(x)$ is a concave function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence by the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality)

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{1}{2}\log(1)+\log(2)+\ldots+\log(n)+\frac{1}{2}\log(n+1) &\leq& \int_{1}^{n+1}\log(x)\,dx\\ &=& (n+1)\log(n+1)-n\end{eqnarray*}$$
that translates into
$$ \log(n!)\leq \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log(n+1)-n $$
such that, by exponentiating both sides,
$$ \frac{n!}{(n+1)^n}\leq \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{e^n}$$
that is enough to prove your claim.